# android programming using internet to access web site

Tags: android

I want to access the web site I want to retrieve information from website.  I have found a solution for that but this application is unfortunately stopped any ideas?

```
package pete.android.study;
```

Comment: Have you added the right permissions in Android manifest ?

Comment: I have no errors only when i open it, "Unfortunaltely it has stopped"

Comment: yes I added the INTERNET permission to manifest

Comment: If you are studying, then one of the first things you should do is learn how to use the debugger and logcat.  For now, please post the stack trace for the exception from logcat.

Comment: ok i found it wait a minute

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: @inflacort Which version of Android are you using?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 20:38:57.489: E/AndroidRuntime(894): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ipk/com.example.ipk.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.ipk.MainActivity
12-02 20:38:57.489: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)   .........

Comment: Please edit your question and post your manifest.

Comment: your error is in `MainActivity` but you post the code of `JSoupStudyActivity`

Comment: No, I fixed as JSoupStudyActivity but still the same error

Comment: So you forget to update the references in manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Your Activity name and package is wrong.

In your manifest, your Main Activity is specified to be `com.example.ipk.MainActivity`. However, the Activity you posted, which I'm assuming is the one you want as your Main Activity, is `pete.android.study.JSoupStudyActivity`.

To fix this, change the

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ipk"
```

to

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pete.android.study"
```

And change:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" >
            </category>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

to

```
    <activity android:name=".JSoupStudyActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" >
            </category>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Once he will have fixed all this stuff, be prepared for NetworkOnMainThreadException :-p

Comment: @Waza_Be One problem at a time :P

Comment: That's always the problem when people cannot start with a simple hellow world they feel like they have to start a network stuff, then parsing, then UI modification, copy paste the whole stuff and then realize they should have started with a simple example

Comment: Yep. I remember writing a hello world to figure out the basic lifecycle and stuff, and then a knots and crosses game using just the standard widgets. There are so many people out here who would benefit greatly from reading the commonsware books or browsing Vogella.de from the basics onwards. It takes them step by step, while most online tutorials will throw code at them and expect them to understand.

Comment: @Raghav Sood I fixed but still same , stopped :S

Comment: @inflacort Please edit your manifest and the complete logcat into your question. I suspect you're getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` now.

Answer (score 0):

android OS >=3.0 does not allow `Network Requests` on Main `UI` thread.

you can use

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this purpose.

Comment: AsyncTask what kind of solution I havent use yet? can you please some information about it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a NetworkOnMainThreadException

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.

```
Runnable blogSearch = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         final String text = getBlogStats();
         JSoupStudyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText(text);
            }
         });
      }
   };

Thread thread = new Thread(null, blogSearch, "MyThread");
thread.start();
```